# Arithmetic right shift gives bogus result?

Tags: c++, gcc, undefined-behavior, bit-shift

I must be absolutely crazy here, but `gcc 4.7.3` on my machine is giving the most absurd result.  Here is the exact code that I'm testing:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  unsigned int b = 100000;
  cout << (b>>b) << endl;
  b = b >> b;
  cout << b << endl;
  b >>= b;
  cout << b << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Now, any number that's right shifted by itself should result in **0** (`n/(2^n) ==  0` with *integer divide*, `n>1`, and *positive/unsigned*), but somehow here is my output:

```
100000
100000
100000
```

Am I crazy?  What could possibly be going on?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: That assumes the compiler even bothers putting in an instruction. It's well within its right to just reject this program.

Comment: @MSalters indeed, we are getting into compiler/platform/version specific at this point but for current and recent versions this is the case and as I already stated it is undefined so you are clearly on your own, `gcc` only seems to produce a `shr` when using `-O0`.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Intel is just one of the many platforms supported by gcc, and they have different optimization stages. A common trick in optimization is to say "This value can only be between 0 and 31 because it's used in a shift, if I follow code path X to get here the value would not be between 0 and 31, so code path X is impossible and I don't even need to generate instructions for it". GCC famously does this for null pointer checks.

Comment: @MSalters that makes sense, so this would effect warnings as well?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Hopefully, but the experience with GCC silently removing flawed null pointer checks tells us that you can't rely on it.

Comment: @davmac: Compilers can and do optimize on future _unavoidable_ undefined behavior. It gets really interesting when externally visible side effects become involved.

Comment: > Comments are becoming a discussion, please ask a new question.

Comment: A fun fact: though this is *undefined* behavior in C, it is *defined* behavior in C#, but the definition is somewhat bizarre. In C#, `x>>y` for 32 bit ints x and y is computed as `x>>(y&0x1f)` ! So `(x >> 16) >> 16` is zero, but `x >> 32` is x.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In C++ as in C, shifts are limited to the size (in bits) of the value shifted. For instance, if unsigned int is 32 bits, then a shift of more than 31 is undefined.

In practice, a common result is that the 5 least-significant bits of the shift amount are used and the higher order bits are ignored; this is due to the compiler producing a machine instruction which does exactly that (eg SHR on x86).

In this case, the shift value is `100000` (decimal) which happens to be `11000011010100000` in binary - the lower 5 bits are zero. So, you're effectively getting a shift by 0. You shouldn't rely on this however; technically, what you're seeing is *undefined behaviour*.

References:

For C, [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 6.5.7:

> If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or
>   equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is
>   undefined.

For C++, [N3690](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf) section 5.8 "[expr.shift]":

> The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater
>   than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand.

N1570 is a draft, nearly identical to the released ISO C11 standard; this clause has been pretty much the same since the 1989 ANSI C standard.

N3690 is a recent draft of the C++ standard; I'm not sure whether it's the best one to use, but again, this clause hasn't changed.

Comment: Did you observe this behavior with different compilers  or read from some where?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, this is documented in the C and C++ standard specifications. Regarding generation of the SHR instruction, I have observed this.

Comment: Holy mother of coding... I just tested this and the binary of 100000 is `0b110000110101_00000`.  I tried shifting by 100001, and it indeed shifted by 1.

Comment: @Aggieboy It will also depend other things such as optimization level `gcc` and `clang` have different output at different optimization levels which is completely consistent with undefined behavior i.e. anything can really happen.

Answer (score 32):

You are invoking [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if you shift greater than the bit length of the left operand, the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `5.8` *Shift operators* paragraph *1* says(*emphasis mine*):

> The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral promotions are performed. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. **The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand.**

Interesting to note that both `gcc` and `clang` *may* generate a warning for this code if the shift amount if a *literal*:

```
cout << (b>> 100000) ;
```

or if `b` is a *const*, the warning for `gcc` is as follows:

```
warning: right shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]
```

as MSalters points out in the comments to the question, we may not be able to even rely on this warning since this is *undefined behavior*, which is consistent with the standards note on *undefined behavior* in the *terms and definitions* section which says:

> Note: [...] Permissible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message). [...]

**Platform specific details**

A potential explanation for the apparent lack of a shift in the example code may be because on some platforms the shift count will be *masked* to `5 bits` for example on an `x86` architecture we can see the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf) section *SAL/SAR/SHL/SHR—Shift* in the *IA-32 Architecture Compatibility* section says:

> The 8086 does not mask the shift count. However, all other IA-32 processors (starting with the Intel 286 processor) do mask the shift count to 5 bits, resulting in a maximum count of 31. [...]

Comment: The 80286 deliberately allowed shift amounts up to the word size, inclusive.  I wonder why the 80386 did not do likewise (using 6 bits of CL when the operand size was 32 bits)?

Comment: Also see [this blog post](https://david.wragg.org/blog/2012/11/shift-instructions.html) for more background on x86.